# Update SHA512 Password in php for a Modoboa Mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, sha512

`Modoboa` is a webadmin mail to manage a mail service.

I try to update the password plugin of roundcube for mobodoa schematic. Modoboa's user passwords have a sha512 crpyt but i dont know how generate this password

This is a part of roundcube plugin configuraion:

```
$config['password_query'] = 'UPDATE mailserver_modoboa.core_user SET password="{SHA512-CRYPT}'.crypt('%p','$6$rounds=70000$'.base64_encode(substr(str_shuffle("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345‌​6789"), 0, 16))).'" WHERE email=%u LIMIT 1';
$config['password_crypt_hash'] = 'sha512';
```

but this query dont work and i dont know how crpyt the password for the new schematic

Passwords look like this in password database field:

```
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$rounds=70000$QQtu7FA6/RXK.qc/$o5UGjhN8q1x3Kxxw0Uk50eX.l0jYEnOWca4oSmZuwFTRf3hkwCEQITI6RNgqc8wqzfcCAv9aMXpF/Bb3iovAZ/
```

How can I generate this password?

Comment: What's the `.....` for? The encrypted string?

Comment: Yes. I edited my question with full demo password

Comment: How can update my password?